# Uncaught TypeError: Object (JS Function) has no method 'apply'

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, highcharts

I want handle event click with chart of django-chartit and bellow is python code.

```
def basicpie(request, title, code, doc, sidebar_items):

    def monthname(month_num):
        names ={1: 'Jan', 2: 'Feb', 3: 'Mar', 4: 'Apr', 5: 'May', 6: 'Jun',
            7: 'Jul', 8: 'Aug', 9: 'Sep', 10: 'Oct', 11: 'Nov', 12: 'Dec'}
        return names[month_num]


    ds = DataPool(
       series=
        [{'options': {
            'source': MonthlyWeatherByCity.objects.all()},
          'terms': [
            'month',
            'boston_temp']}
         ])

    cht = Chart(
        datasource = ds,
        series_options =
          [{'options':{
              'type': 'pie',
              'stacking': False},
            'terms':{
              'month': [
                'boston_temp']
              }}],
        chart_options =
          {'title': {
               'text': 'Monthly Temperature of Boston'},

            'plotOptions': {
              'series': {
                "cursor": "pointer",
                'point': {
                  'events': {
                    'click': 'function() {alert(\'clicked\');}'
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
        x_sortf_mapf_mts = (None, monthname, False))

    return render_to_response('chart_code.html', {'chart_list': cht,
                                         'code': code,
                                         'title': title,
                                         'doc': doc,
                                         'sidebar_items': sidebar_items})
```

and javascript code of django-chartit

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each(_chartit_hco_array, function(index, chartoptions) {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartoptions);
    });
});
```

but i get following error when I click on the chart.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function() {alert('clicked');} has no method 'apply'.
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Should it be `'click': function() {alert('clicked');}`?

Comment: why is `'click': 'function() {alert(\'clicked\');}'` in quotes?

Comment: `"foobar".apply()` throws the same error

Comment: My guess: because it probably comes from a bad JSON copy/paste. For some reason, syntax highlighting is invisible to newcomers, when it should be the first clue that something is not right.

Comment: @elclanrs To me it looks like he intended it to be in quotes, since he escaped the inner quotes.

Comment: Perhaps because all the other options are in quotes... I had a look for an example of a `click` option in the documentation but couldn't find any. I'm assuming like you that it needs to be not quoted for `apply` to work its magic.

Comment: I'm not sure if that was or wasn't written by OP directly, as the inconsistency of double quotes in line above `"cursor": "pointer"` suggests that something was edited or copy/pasted, maybe from JSON as all keys are quoted, but dunno... The error seems pretty clear given the description and possible line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highcharts requires a function for the click param, and you are passing a string.

Use this instead

```
'events': {
         'click': function() {
              alert("clicked");
             }
          }
```

[Here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events) are the docs in Highcharts.

Comment: Thanks @Kelly J Andrews . I want generate code js from python code . If I run directly by javascript code, its is normal